# Sum of each element in python list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I want to add each element of list containing tuples. For example,

```
    >>> list1
    [(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8)]
    >>> list2
    [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
```

Answer should be

```
     list3 = [(1,3,5),(7,9,11),(13,15,17)]
```

Comment: Please vote up and select an answer from one of the three below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

zip is your friend here.

```
result = []
for ta, tb in zip(list1, list2):
     t =tuple(a+b for a, b in zip(ta, tb))
     result.append(t)

print result
>> [(1,3,5),(7,9,11),(13,15,17)]
```

or more pythonic is:

```
result = [tuple(a+b for a, b in zip(ta, tb)) for ta, tb in zip(list1, list2)]
print result
>> [(1,3,5),(7,9,11),(13,15,17)]
```

result could simply be a generator by doing this:

```
result = (tuple(a+b for a, b in zip(ta, tb)) for ta, tb in zip(list1, list2))
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I'd consider the list comprehension there to be more Pythonic.  It's definitely less readable.  Using timeit I timed both snippets and the unrolled for loop was marginally faster as well (about 5%).  Generally yeah, list comps should be preferred, but nested list comps tend to border on unreadable voodoo.

Comment: I agree Adam it's not readable the reason I mention it being more pythonic is that result could very easily then be a generator by changing the brackets. This then means the result is not allocated to mem or iterated through until it is needed. See modification above...

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> list1 = [(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8)]
>>> list2 = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
>>> [tuple(map(sum, zip(*i))) for i in zip(list1, list2)]
[(1, 3, 5), (7, 9, 11), (13, 15, 17)]
```

The nice thing about doing it this way is that it also works for an arbitrary number of lists

```
>>> list3 = [tuple(map(sum, zip(*i))) for i in zip(list1, list2)]
>>> [tuple(map(sum, zip(*i))) for i in zip(list1, list2, list3)]
[(2, 6, 10), (14, 18, 22), (26, 30, 34)]
```

Comment: if my list comes as dynamically then how to calculate this kind of things

Comment: @DaSaDiYaChaiTAnYa, not sure what you mean. Can you give an example?

Comment: okey no problem i had resolved it from my side my question is above answer use the two different list like list1 and list2 but when there are the list comes from the dynamically then how to resolve this kind of things ..??

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension, though it's a bit awkward:

```
list3 = [tuple(x + y for x, y in zip(t1, t2))
         for t1, t2 in zip(list1, list2)]
```

If you are fine with a list of lists instead of a lists of tuples, an alternative is

```
list3 = [map(operator.add, *t) for t in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Comment: Interesting how another poster considers the "awkward" code "more pythonic".

Comment: If the OP has 11 rep, I'd call it awkward too! I thought the same thing, and consulted [google's python style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html#List_Comprehensions) to help clarify. Honestly, it didn't help much.

Comment: Fun fact: the map() version above was ~50% faster than the list comp in my experiments (using timeit), and yet map is still a function that is frowned upon in the Python community.

Comment: @Adam, I wouldn't say it's frowned upon, but there are only a relatively few specific cases where it still makes sense to use map over list comprehensions and it takes a fair while to learn when it should be used.

Comment: (+1)  And the OP could wrap `tuple()` around `imap()` if he really needs a `tuple`.

Comment: To clarify: I didn't mean map was frowned upon in the sense of being formally deprecated, but [this article by Guido](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) seems to indicate a certain amount of "you can use them, but you're better of doing this", which is what I meant.  And FWIW, the Python style checker PyLint will actually flag calls to map as warnings, further indicating a certain "maybe you should reconsider using it" vibe.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> [tuple(sum(pair) for pair in zip(a,b)) for a,b in zip(list1,list2)]
[(1, 3, 5), (7, 9, 11), (13, 15, 17)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: The below is not at all needed. The `map` builtin automatically zips multiple iterables passed to it, so `zip_with(func, iter1, iter2)` can be replaced by `map` with the same arguments.

```
map(functools.partial(map, op.add), list1, list2)
```

---

### This section isn't needed

Here's a snippet implementing something along the lines of Haskell's `zipWith`

```
def zip_with(func, xs, ys):
    return [func(x, y) for (x, y) in zip(xs, ys)]
```

---

```
In [1]: def zip_with(func, xs, ys):
   ...:         return [func(x, y) for (x, y) in zip(xs, ys)]
   ...: 

In [2]: import operator as op

In [3]: zip_with(op.add, [1,2,3], [4,5,6])
Out[3]: [5, 7, 9]

In [4]: import functools

In [5]: zip_with(functools.partial(zip_with, op.add), list1, list2)
Out[5]: [[1, 3, 5], [7, 9, 11], [13, 15, 17]]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import operator
list3 = [tuple(map(operator.add, list1[i], list2[i]))
 for i in range(len(list1))]
```